# Practical application of lattice knots

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I am looking for examples of practical applications of lattice knots. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two references that explore lattice knots to illuminate questions
in knotted polymers and knotted DNA:

> Orlandini, Enzo, Attilio L. Stella, and Carlo Vanderzande. "The size of knots in polymers." *Physical biology* 6.2 (2009): 025012.
>   ([journal link](http://iopscience.iop.org/1478-3975/6/2/025012/fulltext/))
>   
>    
>    
>    
>    
>   [image]
>
> Janse van Rensburg, E. J., et al. "The writhe of knots in the cubic lattice." *Journal of Knot Theory and Its Ramifications* 6.01 (1997): 31-44. ([journal link](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218216597000042))